# all queries are uppercase with oracle driver with laravel query builder

Tags: php, database, oracle, laravel, oci8

I'm using https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8 for connecting to oracle database in my project. 
the problem is all of my queries turns to uppercase.

```
DB::table('users')->select('FirstName')->get();
```

this returns error saying invalid identifier "FIRSTNAME"

```
QueryException
Error Code : 904
Error Message : ORA-00904: "FIRSTNAME": invalid identifier
Position : 69
```

Comment: Your users table doesn't have a FirstName field? Could you try and add that field to users and retry?

Comment: it has exactly the "FirstName" column @DanielO.

Comment: Can you try: DB::table('users')->select('*')->get();

Comment: yes , and it returns all of my data @DanielO.

Comment: Unless enclosed in double quotes, Oracle table/column etc names are treated as uppercase. I'm guessing your users table is actually USERS not "users". It is often simplest to avoid lowercase/mixed case identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered with the same problem, just comment on line 206 of the file OracleGrammar.php that will be solved, it tests if it is a reserved word back with the names in uppercase.

//$value = $this->isReserved($value) ? Str::lower($value) : Str::upper($value);

Comment: The file path is
vendor->yajra->laravel-oci8->src->Oci8->query->Grammars